# how to save the selected/checked items in a listbox in nana gui c++

Tags: c++, nana

```
int main()
{
    using namespace nana;

    form fm;
    listbox lb(fm, nana::rectangle(10, 10, 280, 120));

    auto cat = lb.at(0);
    if (cat.begin() == cat.end())
        std::wcout <<  ("true ");
    else        
        std::wcout <<  ("false ");

    std::wcout << "\n";

    lb.append_header( ("Name"), 100);
    lb.append_header( ("Gender"), 60);
    lb.append_header( ("Age"), 60);

    //lb.resolver(resolver()); //Pass the user defined resolver to the listbox

    person pr;
    pr.name =  ("Peter");
    pr.gender = true;
    pr.age = 10;
    lb.at(0).append (pr); //person to item. resolver::decode() is required

    person prr;
    lb.at(0).at(0).resolve_to( prr); //item to person. resolver::encode() is required
    std::cout << pr << "\n";
    std::cout << prr << "\n";
    fm.show();
    exec();
}
```

I am trying to get the data checked in the list
I tried the
selected()/checked() functions but I am not sure how to use them
as I don't have much knowledge about it

this is the Nanapro gui library , with c++14